# FaceBook logging out when getting error on a request

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

So I am using the Facebook iOS SDK and I get this very annoying thing where I am getting logged out when a request to the open graph fails. How do I prevent this from happening? Here's how I am posting it:

```
 [_facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath
                              andParams:params 
                          andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                            andDelegate:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fb SDK is a complete mess, but what you could do:

- set your object to be a delegate
- implement protocol methods that catches error

  - in that methods check if you're still logged in
  - if not - login, or do whatever you want (present error alert/start another request/etc)